# woocommerce get original item unit price in order

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I want to display the item unit price (include sale price,and regular price ) in the customer email and customer view order page.

In woocommerce order line item object, you are only can see the item line subtotal, subtotal , qty..etc. But it doesn't show the original price unit price (including regular price and sale price) in the data. At most I can get the unit price by adding the discounted amount and line subtotal. But it is no way I know if the item is in sale or not as well as the responding price.

Right now I can use the following codes to get the unit price in order item:

```
$product = $item->get_product();
$product->get_price_html();
```

The problem with this `get_price_html()` is display the real time product price. Which means if I changed the product price after sometime, then the price in previous order details will changed as well. This will caused a lot of confusion when someone view the older order.

So how can I get the original unit price of the line item in order details?

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the best answer. But seeing that it is still unanswered. I have tried `$item->get_price();` and it returns it's an undefined function. However based on my problem I was able to use `$item->get_total()` and `$item->get_quantity()`. Based on this, I can just divide price by total. This is my temporary fix:

```
            foreach ($items as $item):
                $product_name = $item->get_name();
                $product_price = $item->get_total();
                $product_quantity = $item->get_quantity();
                //This gets per unit price
                $unit_price = $product_price / $product_quantity;
                ?>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <?= $product_name ?>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <?= number_format($unit_price, 2) ?> / Unit
                </td>
                <td>
                    <?= $product_quantity ?>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <?= number_format($product_price, 2) ?>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <?php
            endforeach;
```

**Update:**

https://www.businessbloomer.com/woocommerce-easily-get-order-info-total-items-etc-from-order-object/

Easy way to select everything in your order.

Comment: Dividing the line total by the quantity will get you the discounted price of an item at the time the order was recorded, but not the item's regular price.  Unfortunately, it doesn't appear that the price is stored with order item data.  At least, not that I can see.  I'm in the same boat as @dev-jim. IF you can determine the amount of discount that was applied, you can work backward from there.